# How to get the coordinates in an image for a cursor position?

Tags: html, typescript, angular5, ngdraggable

It is like placing different dishes over a dining table. I have an image(table) and i need to drag and place other small things(div) over the image. I need to get the coordinates in percentage w.r.t the image(table) size. I don't even know which is the event to be used. Please help.

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 mrg-btm-zero">

     <!-- TODO: Change number of dishes w.r.t table name selection-->
     <div ngDraggable [handle]="dishA" class="mrg-right-10 float-left">
          <div #DishA class="dishes"></div>
     </div>
     <div ngDraggable [handle]="dishB" class="mrg-right-10 float-left">
          <div #DishB class="dishes"></div>
     </div>
     <div ngDraggable [handle]="dishC" class="mrg-right-10 float-left">
          <div #DishC class="dishes"></div>
     </div>

     <div class="Dinetable">
          <!-- TODO: Change table image w.r.t table name selection-->
          <img src="../../../../../assets/images/tableType1.png" />
     </div>

 </div>
```

i have [this](https://jsfiddle.net/gabrieleromanato/MxYGZ/) link. But don't know to use it in typescript. Also i need the percentage of coordinates from a responsive page.

Comment: Still, i don't have a solution. Please help

Comment: Is there any 3rd party control to handle such an image?